# One Xcode with 2 developers?

Tags: xcode

My `Xcode` used to be registered under  my own developer program .
There is a company with their own developer program , that used to upload apps
from their own mac .

I would like to upload a build from my mac and my `Xcode`, using their developer program.

Do i need to create a new `certificate` to my `Xcode`/mac from the beginning for that ?
Can i just download their `certificates` and `provisioning` , drag to my `Xcode` and just upload a build to their program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the right combination of certificate, provisioning profile, and bundle id, you can build the app from any Mac using any Xcode (assuming it supports the necessary SDK and device versions).

It would be cleaner to have your developer ID included in their team so that Xcode can manage profile changes and get updates but it's not necessary.

(Note: you use Keychain Access for certificates, not Xcode.)

Comment: Thanks, i am not sure i get your last sentence, to import their certificate from the dev center to Xcode, i just have to  drag it right? (then the same with provisioning profiles) ?